# agent cannot be resolved to a variable when timing segments of AnyLogic model

Tags: anylogic

In the model, I need to time segments in which some agents go through, but not all, rendering the use of timeMeasureStart and End blocks ineffective as any agents who go through a certain End block MUST go through it's corresponding Start block, but not all agents that will encounter the End block will have gone through it's corresponding Start block.

I have done the following and receive the error that 'agent cannot be resolved to a variable' in the Histogram

1. Defined the variables `startTime` `endTime` `cycleTime` in the agent class Patient which is being pushed through the model.
2. Put `agent.cycleTime=agent.endTime-agent.startTime;` in the On enter slot of the block in which I want the timing to end.
3. Defined a Histogram Data called `myDataSet` with the Value `agent.cycleTime` in Main
4. Made a histogram in Main which takes `myDataSet` in it's Histogram slot.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can still use `TimeMeasureStart/end` blocks. Just let some agents bypass them with a `SelectOutput` block upstream of the `TimeMeasureStart` block. The condition would be determined by who should be measured.

Ok, then to your details:

> Put agent.cycleTime=agent.endTime-agent.startTime; in the On enter slot of the block in which I want the timing to end.

This is not how you would measure time. The variables are a good start, though. Do this instead:

1. Wherever timing should start, you write `agent.startTime = time()` (logs curr model time)
2. Wherever timing should end, you write `agent.cycleTime = time() - agent.startTime`, essentially measuring how much time has passed since the start.
3. Now you do what you want with `agent.cycletime`

> Defined a Histogram Data called myDataSet with the Value agent.cycleTime in Main

this is not how you use Histogram Data. You need to use the API calls on it properly, for example `myHistogramData.add(someValue)`: [image]

Also, always check example models and the help, many issues can be solved by checking those first :)

Comment: I have edited my question to explain my situation a little better. I believe according to this situation, I will add a ```selectOutput``` just before an agent encounters the ```timeMeasureEnd``` block, and add logic in that ```selectOutput``` block that will acknowledge whether an agent passing through it has passed through a certain ```timeMeasureEnd``` block, then route the agent around the ```timeMeasureEnd``` if it hasn't been through the ```timeMeasureStart```. Seem logical?

Comment: Just route them around the start block and you are set. The End blocks only measure those that went through a start block

Comment: The issue is that agents who have not went through an End block's corresponding Start block cause in error in the model. Not all agents in the model go through the branch that has the Start block. This is why I am trying to route around the End block instead

Comment: then do that :)

Comment: so the required condition to be given would be in the selectoutput along the lines of ```agent.timeMeasureStart```. Would anything need to be declared in the agent or in the ```timeMeasureStart```?

Comment: Nope. Best open a new issue with the specific question, SOF does not work well for this back&forth :) . Also, there are issues on exactly this question already, maybe a quick search helps before even asking a new question :)